# How to determine when spawned process is ready? (Using CreateProcess() and FindWindow())

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

This should be an easy one: I am creating a program that spawns a process using the win32 `CreateProcess()` function. Once this process is loaded, I find its window using `FindWindow` and send it messages using `SendMessage()`. The question is, **how do I know when that window is ready to accept messages?**

Consider the following:

```
HWND wnd;

BOOL Start()
{
  // Spawn the process
  if (! CreateProcess(...))
    return FALSE;

  // Find the process's window (class and name already known)
  wnd = FindWindow(MY_WINDOW_CLASS, MY_WINDOW_NAME);

  // Always returns FALSE because window has not yet been created.
  return (wnd != NULL);
}
```

The code above will (almost?) always fail; the window cannot be created and found that quickly. If I put a thread wait, say `Sleep(1000)`, between the `CreateProcess` and `FindWindow` calls, it works fine. But this feels like a *very* bad hack.

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Edit): [User IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) pointed out problems with `WaitForInputIdle()`, and suggested [CBT Hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

> (...) callback function used with the [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
>   function. The system calls this function before activating,
>   creating, (...) a window; (... many other things).

Also, CBT is short for computer-based training, for whatever reason.

(Old, beware, see comments.) You are looking for [WaitForInputIdle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687022%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Quote:

> When a parent process creates a child
>   process, the CreateProcess function
>   returns without waiting for the child
>   process to finish its initialization.
>   Before trying to communicate with the
>   child process, the parent process can
>   use the WaitForInputIdle function to
>   determine when the child's
>   initialization has been completed.

Comment: The Windows API is so huge nobody can expect to know it all. I learned something new today, thanks.

Comment: This is a bug waiting to happen. `WaitForInputIdle` was invented to address the requirements of DDE. Using it for anything else is going to fail, in the most subtle ways. Relevant reading: [WaitForInputIdle should really be called WaitForProcessStartupComplete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100325-00/?p=14493) and [WaitForInputIdle waits for any thread, which might not be the thread you care about](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100326-00/?p=14483).

Comment: Thanks for bringing those two articles from _The Old New Thing_ to my attention; the story, as always, is more complicated than it may seem at first, and this blog is a treasure trove. However, I disagree that `WaitForInputIdle()` cannot be used in this context; the method returns once all threads have been idle at once for the first time (mostly good enough for the Q), and handling `FindWindow() == null` remains necessary even when using explicit synchronization using a named event (or similar). Rather sadly, I also don't know of any better method, except for looping to hell.

Comment: @gimpf: *"the method returns once all threads have been idle at once for the first time"* - That's not, what the blog article says. The function returns as soon as **one** thread in the target process has reached a point, where it can process messages. This could be the thread displaying a splash screen, or some background worker thread. `WaitForInputIdle` is most definitely not good enough for this particular scenario. A CBT hook would be a clean solution to the question asked. No polling required; the callback is called, when a window is being created.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for your patient corrections. I re-read, and yes, it's _any_ thread, not _all_. I didn't know about the CBT hook, that one seems like a workable solution without target application modification. I'm adding a link to that.

Comment: Instead of using `SetWindowsHookEx()` with a `WH_CBT` hook, you can alternatively use [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) to handle `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE` and/or `EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW` events. Even the hook documentation suggests using [`WinEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) instead of hooks whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [WaitForInputIdle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687022%28VS.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: [I have](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33410894/1889329). It's certainly not what you'd want to use.

Answer (score 1):

If the process you're starting is one you can change, have it send a message back to the parent when it is ready.  You can pass the HWND of the parent as a command line parameter, or use `FindWindow` if you can guarantee that the parent will be unique.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the source code of both processes is under your control.

- You can let the second process post a message to the first when it's ready, if the second knows the needed details of the first process' message window.
- Or you can wait in the first process for an agreed-upon named synchronization object, like event or mutex, being set from the second process.