# WINAPI VirtualQueryEx - invalid handle

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to read some pages of memory of a 32 bit process using [VirtualQueryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx) using Visual Studio 2012.

However when I run the program I get VirtualQueryEx Error 6: Invalid Handle. However there is no error with the handle itself [hProcess] and I am passing in the appropriate parameters. What could be it?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//  Forward declarations:
BOOL GetProcessList( );
BOOL ListProcessModules( DWORD dwPID );
BOOL ListProcessThreads( DWORD dwOwnerPID );
void printError( TCHAR* msg );

int main( void )
{
  GetProcessList( );
   system("pause");

  return 0;
}

BOOL GetProcessList( )
{
  HANDLE hProcessSnap;
  HANDLE hProcess;
  PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
  DWORD dwPriorityClass;

  // Take a snapshot of all processes in the system.
  hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
  if( hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
  {
    printError( TEXT("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of processes)") );
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Set the size of the structure before using it.
  pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

  // Retrieve information about the first process,
  // and exit if unsuccessful
  if( !Process32First( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) )
  {
    printError( TEXT("Process32First") ); // show cause of failure
    CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );          // clean the snapshot object
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Now walk the snapshot of processes, and
  // display information about each process in turn
  do
  {
    //If the process name equals foo_process.exe
if (!_tcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, _T("foo_process.exe"))) 
{

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, pe32.th32ProcessID );
    if( hProcess == NULL )
      printError( TEXT("OpenProcess") );

    unsigned char *addr = NULL;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;

    if (VirtualQueryEx(hProcess, addr, &meminfo, sizeof(meminfo)) == 0){
         printError( TEXT("VirtualQueryEx") );
         //return FALSE;
    }

}
  } while( Process32Next( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) );

  CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );

  return( TRUE );
}

void printError( TCHAR* msg )
{
 ...
}
```

EDIT: Handle has value:
[image]

EDIT 2: More Info:

- Windows 7 64bit  platform.
- Visual Studio 2012 (32 bit debugger) ran
  as Administrator
- Process is *32 (32bit)

Comment: You are passing NULL to the `lpAddress` parameter of `VirtualQueryEx()`, are you sure that is valid? It is not documented as an allowed value.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: *lpAddress* is annotated `_In_opt_`. Although not specifically documented, this implies that `nullptr` is valid. If it wasn't valid I'd expect to see `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, not `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

Comment: `there is no error with the handle itself [hProcess]` Are you positive about that? `VirtualQueryEx()` will return `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` if passed a NULL hProcess, which could happen if for example your app runs normally and tries to OpenProcess an elevated `"foo_process.exe"`.

Comment: @dxiv Please see the picture I added. There is a value, its not null according to when i debugged it

Comment: Sorry, not able to duplicate. I ran a quick test with your code, and didn't find a case where a valid `hProcess` caused an `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. Do you get the same error if trying to look at `notepad.exe` (while it's running, of course), or is there something special about `"foo_process.exe"`.

Comment: Are you *certain* that the target process is 32-bit?

Comment: 64 bit process seems most likely

Comment: My crystal ball says that the process is not yet initialized.  Most likely by passing CREATE_SUSPENDED to the CreateProcess() call.

Comment: @HansPassant: Reading the documentation for the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` [Process Creation Flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863.aspx), it doesn't sound like it prevents (or defers) process initialization. Everything is created and initialized as usual, with the exception that the primary thread is created in suspended state. Am I reading something into the documentation that isn't there?

Comment: Covered well in [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863882/error-invalid-handle-when-calling-getmodulefilenameex-after-createprocess) and [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150716-00/?p=45131).

Comment: @HansPassant: Incredibly useful information, as always. I wasn't aware of the self-initialization nature of processes. I guess this is a case, where implementation details do surface at the interface. I wasn't able to produce any official information searching the MSDN (except for a subtle hint in the [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) documentation referring to process initialization). Are my Google-Fu/Bing-Jutsu not strong enough, or is this simply not documented?

Comment: Not sure whether that is relevant in this scenario.  An uninitialized process may not have any modules loaded, but it must have an address space.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry for the late reply but if I change it to 'notepad.exe' it gives me the same error. Maybe it is a platform dependent issue. I don't understand the conversation above so don't know if its that.

Comment: This would be a good time to edit your post and add *all* possibly relevant info - OS, bitness, project settings (ansi/unicode, 32/64b), environment (anti-virus, unusual local policies), user account (admin or not), normal/elevated execution etc.

Comment: @dxiv I gave more info. By the way what environment did you run on for it to work?

Comment: Win7 Sp1 x64, VS 2012 Up4, program compiled as a 32b non-Unicode console app, and run normally (not elevated) either from the debugger or standalone at the cmd prompt (with some printf added).

Comment: P.S. At this point I would suggest you upload a minimal, complete, compilable project somewhere ([Stack Overflow Etiquette for Sharing Files and Resources](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources)) so that others don't have to fill-in the blanks or second-guess the project settings. Just as an example, if the real `printError` function has a bug of the buffer-overflow variety, then all the comments posted so far could be moot.

Answer (score -1):

> unsigned char *addr = NULL;

You're asking VirtualQueryEx to Query address 0 which is not valid, causing the failure.

Comment: An invalid address would at worst cause an ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, not OP's ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. See the comments from 5 years ago and/or try it for yourself.