# Start Process and Always Set Process HWND Dimensions

Tags: c, winapi

I am starting another application and setting its main HWND position and size. I am using the `STARTUPINFO` flags to specify the window dimensions but it looks like these dimensions are only followed if the new process uses `CW_USEDEFAULT` in its `CreateWindow()` function.

Is there a flag/setting in `STARTUPINFO` that will always set the new processes HWND dimensions? I know another solution it to find the processes main HWND and `SetWindowPos()` but that involves enumerating all windows to find the right one and some applications take a while to startup so the window is alive by the time I call `EnumWindows()`

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

si.dwX = x;
si.dwY = y;
si.dwXSize = w;
si.dwYSize = h;

// any flags I can set to give the STARTUPINFO dimensions priority?
si.dwFlags = ??

CreateProcess(_T("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"), _T(""),
NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL,
NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a flag/setting in STARTUPINFO that will always set the new processes HWND dimensions?

No.  The spawned process has total control over its UI.  It chooses whether to use defaults or not.  What you specify in `STARTUPINFO` are defaults only.

> I know another solution it to find the processes main HWND and SetWindowPos()

If you want to *force* the dimensions, yes.

> that involves enumerating all windows to find the right one and some applications take a while to startup so the window is alive by the time I call EnumWindows()

Try calling [`WaitForInputIdle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022.aspx) first ([caveat #1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100325-00/?p=14493), [caveat #2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100326-00/?p=14483)).

Or, use [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) to monitor window creations until you see the window you are interested in.

Related: [How to determine when spawned process is ready? (Using CreateProcess() and FindWindow())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107499/)